# Best Practice: How to ensure and modify a String so that it is a valid URL

Tags: java, url

I have a application which requires the user to input some values. From these values a URL is generated. However if the user enters special symbols like e.g. german vowels or other strange symbol, there is an exception when I try to create a URL. So i have two questions:

1. What is the best way to detect if a URL is a well-formed URL?
2. How should i convert a invalid URL into a valid URL? I know this want work, but I'd like if from a invalid URL a valid URL is generated that is as similar as possible to the original URL: for example [http://www.äüö.com](http://www.%C3%A4%C3%BC%C3%B6.com) is modified to http://www.auo.com

Comment: For (1) are you looking for "valid" or "well formed"? In my mind, valid = the URL actually exists and is (generally) responsive. "well formed" means that it may not exist but the syntax is conformant.

Comment: ah sorry it hast to be well formed

Comment: Thanks. Next question: which language/environment? Some have some pretty nifty built-ins for checking the well-formedness of a URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`java.net.URL`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URL.html) in the Android Java runtime behaves much like the Sun Java class of the same name.  Its constructor throws a `MalformedURLException` if the URL is malformed.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure you should do that anymore, since now one can register domain names using native characters, like www.sãopaulo.com , which could be different from www.saopaulo.com .
That's also valid for russian, chinese, etc.

Comment: yes there are some special characters which are allowed, however e.g. whitespaces aren't possible.

Comment: yeah, I think you should read the specifications for the new domain names characters to make sure what is or not allowed. I guess it's become even trickier now.

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly suggest that you do *not* attempt to correct (in my mind "guess") a user-entered URL. The security concerns alone are nightmarish. If an invalid URL is entered, throw an exception and proceed accordingly.

Comment: ok, but how can i check without trying to execute if a URL is well formed?